# How to fully remove a GRUNT project

Tags: gruntjs

So I understand that every Grunt project lives in it's folder, but does deleting the folder fully delete the project? I don't think so.

Let's say I have NODE and Grunt CLI installed, and I use grunt-init to create a project based on a template (say "jquery"), how do I delete the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes removing the project folder will remove everything that was installed by your grunt-init.

It will NOT remove anything installed globally (like node or grunt CLI).

Answer (score 0):

I think 'grunt-remove' does exactly that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-remove

Comment: no it doesn't. It just deletes files from the folders you specify.